# redirect to another page with anchor tag in php

Tags: php, anchor

I am trying to echo a URL with anchor tag on the backend page after the script is run which should take to that page and to that location of that page where anchor is placed.

After the form submission it takes to script page where at the end the code is:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=finalpage.php#submitted' />";
```

I have place the anchor on finalpage.php which is way down to header and i want that it should directly take to that anchor:

```
<a name="submitted"></a>
```

The page do refresh taking to finalpage.php, but it takes to the header and not where the anchor tag is.

I tried with Location(header:..), die(...), but not working

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the **id** attribute for the anchor, not the name?

```
<a id="submitted"></a>
```

Comment: yes i tried... and what i marked is that on page load the page flikers... as in it takes to that submitted tag and bounces back to header. That means id is working i guess. Must be any code on the header of finalpage.php which is making it do that. Can't find that though.

Comment: Ahh i found it:
`<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>` this code in header was interfering!

Comment: Ok, nice, so no problem now! :)

Answer (score 0):

The url hash component focuses on the element with its I'd on page load